# Haskell Date parsing

Tags: date, haskell, calendar, aeson

I'm trying to make a FromJSON instance for Data.Time.Calendar's Day type.  I am confused about the types, and this seems like a common enough situation that it ought to be solved.

So the Day type represents a modified Julian date.  And the Data.Time.Calendar module defines "showGregorian", which converts the modified Julian date into a Gregorian date and outputs a String ISO 8601 representation.

The trouble is that Data.Time.Calendar doesn't have a good way to parse an ISO 8601 into a Gregorian date.  If I use the ParseTime class, I can only pass in the string format, and not the calendar for which the string is a representation of a date.  So, effectively, I'd pass in '20140502' and the ParseTime class would treat that string as the string representation of a modified Julian date.

It seems like this ought to be a solved problem.  Ideally, I'd like a solution that does not use date-times.  My model uses Gregorian calendar dates because that is all I need, and those are the things I will be comparing, searching, etc.

Of course, the whole reason for using calendar days when I only need calendar days was so that I wouldn't have to think about how to compare and convert them, but I suppose that is a whine for another day.

Addendum:

Days are defined as:

```
-- | The Modified Julian Day is a standard count of days, with zero being the day 1858-11-17.
newtype Day = ModifiedJulianDay {toModifiedJulianDay :: Integer} deriving (Eq,Ord)
```

This lead me to believe that a Day is not a physical day, but a day in the MJD calendar (under the principle that the exposed documentation should tell us what a type represents, not the representation for the type).

Comment: I am not really sure if I understand exactly what you are after. Recently I was dealing with date parsing pain and I discovered this library which worked very nicely. https://github.com/singpolyma/git-date-haskell Hopefully that helps

Comment: The thing I'm after is a bugless way to parse an ISO 8601 date into a 'Day', which uses the modified Julian calendar.  It looks like Yesod made the mistake I'm trying to avoid (I was looking at its code for an example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why doesn't `parseTime` do exactly what you want?  `parseTime defaultTimeLocale "%F"` is exactly the inverse (up to `Just`) of `showGregorian`, as demonstrated by the following snippet that you can paste into GHCi.

```
import System.Locale 
import Data.Time.Format 
import Data.Time.Calendar

let test = parseTime defaultTimeLocale "%F" . showGregorian :: Day -> Maybe Day
let notIdentity x = case test x of { Nothing -> True; Just x' -> x /= x' }
filter notIdentity [fromGregorian 0 1 1..fromGregorian 3000 12 31]
```

Comment: It does do what I want, as you demonstrate.  But the documentation is unclear.  In particular, '%F' is just a "format" -- a way to parse and present dates.  It's not a calendar.  The library **must** be assuming that a %F formatted date is Gregorian.  That is an undocumented assumption that violates the stated intention of the Day type.  And it still means the library is broken, since it means I can't parseTime into the modified Julian date calendar.  Thanks for your help, I think I'm taking this to the Cafe.

Comment: The `time` documentation can be hard to grok, granted.  However I don't see why you think there's a bug.  Can you demonstrate some buggy behaviour?  A day is not "Gregorian" or "Julian".  It's just a day.  There can be Gregorian or Julian *representations* of it, however.

Comment: Please see the question's addendum.  Basically, the documentation says that a **Day** is an MJD, not a physical day.

Comment: No it doesn't say that.  It describes what a MJD is because it just so happens that `Day` is stored as an MJD.  That doesn't mean a `Day` *is* as MJD.  That's just its representation.  Again, please demonstrate some buggy behaviour.

Comment: The purpose of the documentation is to tell me what a type represents, not what it's representation is.  I don't see why you're asking me to demonstrate buggy behavior when you already demonstrated it.  The documentation does not agree with the implementation.  And I don't see why we're arguing about it.  First, I said I was taking this elsewhere.  Second, the documentation is very clear.  And it's wrong.

Comment: If you are claiming that the documentation is misleading then I agree.  Beyond that I don't see a bug.

Answer (score 2):

The [GHC.Generics](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/GHC-Generics.html) module is making this type of problem very easy to solve.

```
{-# language DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# language StandaloneDeriving #-}

import Data.Aeson
import Data.Time.Calendar

import GHC.Generics

deriving instance Generic Day

instance ToJSON  Day
instance FromJSON  Day
```

Though on reading your comment:

> The thing I'm after is a bugless way to parse an ISO 8601 date into a 'Day', which uses the modified Julian calendar.

This may not be the solution you are looking for.